# Espresso UI test emoji on the device's display

Tags: android, android-espresso, emoji, ui-testing

I am writing UI tests for a chat app using Espresso. I am curious to know if there exists a way, We can test that if a particular emoji is present on the device screen. I have tried on my own but doesn't find any way to do so. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to ascertain if a certain string exists anywhere on screen:

```
public boolean textExists(String text){
    try{
        onView(first(allOf(withText(containsString(text)), isDisplayed()))).perform(closeSoftKeyboard());
        return true;
    }
    catch (NoMatchingViewException e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
boolean emoji = textExists("");
```